# Jetty 9.4.44 - Deployment Failure - ClassCastException

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, classcastexception, jetty-9

I'm trying to setup a Jetty 9.4.44 environment and running into a deployment failure for a vanilla app. The setup uses the stock Jetty and there's no customization. The app just has a welcome page and noting else (no JNDI datasource reference of any kind). Not sure what's causing this failure. Any help here is really appreciated.

Exception Debug Logs

```
2022-01-05 02:33:50.372:DBUG:oejw.WebAppClassLoader:main: getResources META-INF/services/javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory []
2022-01-05 02:33:50.373:DBUG:oejj.InitialContextFactory:main: InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
2022-01-05 02:33:50.375:DBUG:oejj.NamingContext:main: new org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot$NamingRoot@5e3d57c7[name=null,parent=,bindings.size=0]
2022-01-05 02:33:50.376:DBUG:oejj.InitialContextFactory:main: Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@1fb19a0
2022-01-05 02:33:50.396:DBUG:oejjj.javaURLContextFactory:main: >>> new root context requested 
2022-01-05 02:33:50.397:DBUG:oejj.NamingContext:main: new org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext@341814d3[name=null,parent=,bindings.size=0]
2022-01-05 02:33:50.408:DBUG:oejj.NamingContext:main: Adding binding with key=comp obj=Reference Class Name: javax.naming.Context|Type: parser|Content: org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaNameParser| for context=null as comp: javax.naming.Reference:Reference Class Name: javax.naming.Context|Type: parser|Content: org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaNameParser|
2022-01-05 02:33:50.408:DBUG:oejj.NamingContext:main: Looking up name="comp"
2022-01-05 02:33:50.410:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@13d9cbf5{/,file:///tmp/jetty/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-404_war-_-any-16934950088483186433/webapp/,STOPPED}{/var/lib/jetty/webapps/404.war}
java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to class javax.naming.Context (javax.naming.Reference and javax.naming.Context are in module java.naming of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.createEnvContext(EnvConfiguration.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.preConfigure(EnvConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1907)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

The deployment descriptor XML for the war file under webapps -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  
  <Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
  </Array>

  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Env name="JETTY_APPS" />/404.war</Set>
  <Set name="configurationClasses"><Ref refid="plusConfig"/></Set>

</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your `${jetty.base}/webapps/app-404.xml` to just ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Env name="JETTY_APPS" />/404.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

The `Configuration` classes are not meant to be setup on an individual webapp basis like you are attempting.

If you need annotations support, or plus support, then enable one (or both) of those modules on your `${jetty.base}` using the normal (and recommended) `${jetty.base}` and `${jetty.home}` split configuration (there are `annotations` and `plus` named modules available, use them)

One other note, if you are using "stock Jetty and there's no customization", then don't use the `<Env>` xml element, as its got side effects that don't play nice with the various modules that require a forked JVM (such as most logging modules), use the pre-existing `<Property name="jetty.webapps">`, it will work in all `${jetty.base}` setups.

```xml
 <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps"/>/404.war</Set>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did switch the configs as mentioned above and it still gives me the same exception. Do let me know if there's something else I can try here.